# CancellationToken without try catch

Tags: c#, task

Simplifying my project, I have the following methods:

```cs
CancellationTokenSource? CancellationTS;
CancellationToken? CancellationT;

void Bar() {
    CancellationTS?.Cancel();
}

void Foo() {
    CancellationTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationT = CancellationTS.Token;

    new Task(() => {
        bool isCancelled = false;
        try {
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), CancellationT).Wait();
        } catch (TaskCanceledException e) {
            isCancelled = true;
        }
        CancellationT = null;
        CancellationTS = null;
        if (isCancelled) {
            [...]
        } else {
            [...]
        }
    }).Start();
}
```

In reality the `CancellationTS.cancel` is naturally not in a `Task` indicated like this, but triggered by a remote event, but this is not the point.

I'd like to avoid the try catch construct in the `Task`.

Edit:
I was looking for exactly the ManualResetEvent, and I didn't know how to request it in any other way than with the ugly and confusing code I had previously written.

Comment: Before we can help you, we'd need to know why you think the `try`/`catch` is required in the first place. Empty `catch` clauses are an anti-pattern in themselves, so it's really unclear how you've *reached the point of writing this code to begin with*.

Comment: ^^ And that's additional to the other anti-patterns, like using `.Wait()`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , CancellationTS.Cancel() throws a TaskCanceledException

Comment: No, the Cancellation Token (not the Source) may throw a TaskCanceledException but normally you should not catch that - because the task within which it has been thrown has been cancelled and you should normally want the Task itself to move into the Cancelled status rather than RanToCompletion. Even if you wanted to hide cancellation from the consumer of the task, you should do that by catching *specifically* the `TaskCanceledException`, not all exceptions.

Comment: This code just make very little sense to me. You should rarely use `.Wait()`, and you should usually catch exceptions in the outermost layer. What is the actual goal? If there idea is to block until some event there are much more suitable tools, like a [ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.wait?view=net-8.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted behavior could be reproduced much simpler with a manual reset event

```
public void Foo(){
    using var mre = new ManualResetEventSlim();
    Task.Run(()=> {Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); mre.Set();});
    bool wasSet = mre.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
}
```

This will block the thread until either the event is set, or when the 15min timeout occurs. The returned bool can be used to determined if the event was set or if the timeout occurred.